# Объединение 2х бесконечных циклов в python telethon

Tags: python, многопоточность, telegram, asyncio, telethon

У меня есть 2 скрипта по автоматической отправке сообщений от моего имени в канал. Запускаю при помощи параллельного выполнения скриптов. Не очень удобно запускать по 2 сессии. Пытался использовать threading и multiprocessing если просто печатать в консоль то все идеально работает, но при отправке в ТГ у меня то await вне асинхронной функции то они выполняются по очереди то вообще зависает. Будьте добры объясните мне как возможно реализовать объединение этих 2х скриптов под одну сессию

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time


api_id = api_id
api_hash = 'api_hash'

with TelegramClient('me', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Go'))


async def message()   
        while True:
            await client.send_message(chat_id, 'test')
            time.sleep(500)
            await client.send_message(chat_id, 'test2')
            time.sleep(60)


with client:
       client.loop.run_until_complete(message())
```

И

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time


api_id = api_id
api_hash = 'api_hash'

with TelegramClient('me2', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Go2'))
    

async def message2()
    while True:
        await client.send_message(chat_id, 'test3')
        time.sleep(3600)


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(message2())
```

Буду очень признателен за любую помощь!

UPD: Для страдальцев подобных мне

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time


api_id = api_id
api_hash = 'api_hash'

client = TelegramClient('me', api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()


async def message()   
        while True:
            await client.send_message(chat_id, 'test')
            await asyncio.sleep(500)
            await client.send_message(chat_id, 'test2')
            await asyncio.sleep(60)

async def message2()
        while True:
            await client.send_message(chat_id, 'test3')
            await asyncio.sleep(500)

client.loop.create_task(message())
client.loop.create_task(message2()) 
client.loop.run_forever()
```

Спасибо Eri!

Comment: Снова перечитал документы, понял что асинхронность с мнопоточнлстью смешивать не лучшая моя идея и что возможно есть смысл просто взять функцию из нижнего скрипта добавить в верхний и заменить time.sleep который убивает мою асинхронность на sleep из модуля async

UPD: Выполняется только одна часть кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with` в этом коде стоит заминить на присваивание и передать аргументом, а то не понятно в каком контектексте будет колбэк при асинхронном запуске.

Убрать блокирующие функции из кода необходимо. `time.sleep(3600)`
на `await asyncio.sleep(3600)`. Если будет ещё что-то такое - запускать в экзекуторах.

2 таска асинхронно стартуют через:

```
loop.create_task(message(client1))
loop.create_task(message2(client2))
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Привет! Спасибо что откликнулся! Если все как я понял, я with присваиваю переменную client (про time.sleep я сам разобрался но спасибо что упомянул!) и при желании могу запускать обе функции из одной сессии передавая параметром функции имя?

Comment: Огромное спасибо! единственное `client.loop.create_task(message()` Во всем остальном ты был абсолютно прав!