# Отправка сообщений в Telegramm

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Возможно ли написать скрипт *(не важно на каком языке)* который будет с **моего** аккаунта *(не бота)* отправлять с определённо периодичностью отправлять сообщения боту/пользователю. 
И если это возможно дайте, пожалуйста, материалы которые помогут мне написать подобный скрипт.

Comment: telethon, aiogram, pyrogram

Comment: [Вот тут тебе уже готовый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1343181/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-2%D1%85-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-python-telethon)